# Why does `observe` and `observeEvent` behave differently on change of input variable?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I found out a behavior that is at least confusing in Shiny, and I would like to figure out why it occurs.

I have a Shiny app with just a `selectInput` input that allows the selection of multiple values (`multiple = TRUE`) and two observers that listen to changes in the input variable: one that uses `observeEvent` directly on the input variable and one that uses just `observe` with the input variable inside its body.

The weirdness occurs when, in the multiple options, one removes all of the options in the selector. In that case, only the `observe` block of code executes and the `observeEvent` does not.

Why does Shiny do that? Should it work like that?

A minimal working example (you just need to deselect all of the variables):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("select", 
                label = "Multiple choices",
                choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                selected = c(1, 2), 
                multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    # Won't execute with no value selected
    observeEvent(input$select, {
        vec_str <- paste(input$select, collapse = " ")
        print(paste("observeEvent:", vec_str))
    })
    
    # Will execute with no value selected
    observe({
        vec_str <- paste(input$select, collapse = " ")
        print(paste("observe:", vec_str))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in `observeEvent` that allows you to ignore the case when `is.null(input$select)`. Set the argument `ignoreNULL = FALSE` and you get the result you want.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", 
              label = "Multiple choices",
              choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
              selected = c(1, 2), 
              multiple = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   # executes even when input$select is NULL
  observeEvent(input$select, {
    vec_str <- paste(input$select, collapse = " ")
    print(paste("observeEvent:", vec_str))
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # Will execute with no value selected
  observe({
    vec_str <- paste(input$select, collapse = " ")
    print(paste("observe:", vec_str))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and effort to respond to the post. I wasn't aware that was the default behavior of the `observeEvent` function. 
Greatly appreciated!